# Excel fill handle - how to set iteration counter?

Tags: excel, fill

Is it possible by excel fill handle, incrase index containing in string?

i.e:
Have this:

```
catalog/images/1/5start.jpg
```

Need get this:

```
catalog/images/1/6start.jpg
catalog/images/1/7start.jpg
catalog/images/1/8start.jpg
```

or

Have this:

```
catalog/images/1/sta5rt.jpg
```

Need get this:

```
catalog/images/1/sta6rt.jpg
catalog/images/1/sta7rt.jpg
catalog/images/1/sta8rt.jpg
```

Comment: Absolutely possible to do that. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: John Coleman is still best solution, but after copying row excel adding tab char in some cases it can be problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly possible, but easy enough with helper columns:

In `A1` put `catalog/images/1/5`

In `B1` put `start.jpg`

In `C1` put the formula `=A1 & B1`.

Select those three cells, and drag down:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it using combination of UDF and formula. If you wish you can convert it to only VBA.

First put this code in module:

```
Public Function DigitsOnly(sStr As String) As Variant
    Dim oRegExp As Object

    Set oRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With oRegExp
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
        oRegExp.Pattern = "\D"
        DigitsOnly = oRegExp.Replace(sStr, vbNullString)
    End With
End Function
```

Put this formula in cell `A2` and drag it down till you want to increment the number.

> *This formula will assume you have data in cell **`A1`**.*

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,DigitsOnly(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",99)),99))),DigitsOnly(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",99)),99)))+1)
```

[image]